# Margin is moving the parent container and child div instead of just child div

Tags: html, css, parent-child, margin, parent

I'm trying to make a card effect on my personal website for posts I make. Right now, my cards are stacking on top of each other, but I want them come after each other like a Facebook or Instagram feed.

Here's my css:

```
.container {
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #DCDCDC;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
.card {
    margin: 8%;
    background: #DAA80D;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #A0A0A0;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 2%;
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    Bye
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a JSfiddle of the above code where the divs stack: https://jsfiddle.net/nbsqkrc6/

And here's a JSfiddle of code where I try to fix the margin: https://jsfiddle.net/teL7hcj8/1/

I saw an answer to a similar problem that uses `top-margin: -1px`, but that didn't work for my code.

Comment: `position:absolute;` in the `.card` might be the problem.

Comment: keep your second code an check the duplicate to fix the margin issue